# Derivative with respect to dependent variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following functions:

$\tilde{U}=U(x,y+f(x));$

$\tilde{V}=V(x,y+f(x))-f'(x) U(x,y+f(x))$

I have problems using the chain rule when computing $\tilde{U}_x$ and $\tilde{V}_y,$ specially the latter.

How would you perform the derivative?

Comment: What are you differentiating?

Comment: I would like to obtain derivatives of the tilde functions as a function (I guess) of the derivatives of the non-tilde functions

Comment: It's helpful to use placeholder functions, if we let $h(x,y) = x$ and $g(x,y) = y + f(x)$ we can write $\tilde{U} = U(h(x,y),g(x,y))$, so then $\tilde{U}_x = \frac{\partial U(h,g)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial U}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.